# Phonegap Ajax request use the wrong URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, phonegap

I try to write an App with Phonegap. I want to make a ajax request from a php file. At the start, the user have to input a IP adress. I want to use this IP adress for a ajax request, but on a test at my pc, ajax try to call http://ipadress:3000/proxy/http://adressFromUser/getData.php. As app on my tablet, I got the message net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/192.XXX.XXX.XXX)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' gap:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        } body {width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#252525;}
        #frame{
            border: 0px;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
    <div id='result_table'>

    </div>
</body>

    <script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://'+localStorage.getItem("ip")+'/getData.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output_string){
            $('#result_table').append(output_string);
        }
    });
        
</script>
</html>
```

I have tried a lot, with port or not, a get request without ajax and so on. In my config.xml I had added the following:

```
<access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Complete config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name></name>
    <description>

    </description>
    <author email="" href="https://">

    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
        <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
        <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
        <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
        <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
        <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
        <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
        <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
        <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
        <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
        <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
        <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="true" />

        <platform name="ios">
            <icon src="www/img/57.png" width="57" height="57" />
            <icon src="www/img/144.png" width="144" height="144" />
            <icon src="www/img/72.png" width="72" height="72" />
            <icon src="www/img/114.png" width="114" height="114" />
            <icon src="www/img/60.png" width="60" height="60" />
            <icon src="www/img/120.png" width="120" height="120" />
            <icon src="www/img/76.png" width="76" height="76" />
            <icon src="www/img/152.png" width="152" height="152" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="android">
    <platform name="android">
            <icon src="www/img/48.png" qualifier="mdpi" />
            <icon src="www/img/72.png" qualifier="hdpi" />
            <icon src="www/img/96.png" qualifier="xhdpi" />
            <icon src="www/img/144.png" qualifier="xxhdpi" />
            <icon src="www/img/192.png" qualifier="xxxhdpi" />
        </platform>
        <platform name="winphone">
        </platform>
         <icon src="www/img/192.png" />
        </widget>
```

Do you have any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: With phonegap the permission will be create from the config.xml and I cant use uses-permission in the config xml.

Comment: I dont with Android Studio, I use phpStorm. I tried to change the Manifest with:
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest" after="uses-permission">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  </config-file>
But I got an error. Wrong xml config